# Refactor if statements

Tags: c#, refactoring

What is a best way for refactor "if" statements?

My method fragment:

```
if (code == SystemCode.Enum1.ToString())
{
    user.IsEnum1 = result != null;
}

if (code  == SystemCode.Enum2.ToString())
{
    user.IsEnum2 = result != null;
}

if (code  == SystemCode.Enum3.ToString())
{
    user.IsEnum3 = result != null;
}
```

Comment: This would be better in [CodeReview.SE]. Also consider to use [`switch statement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t.aspx) instead of multiple `if statement`.

Comment: or at least else-if's

Comment: @zrabzdn _I don't like else if_ Really? Why? Any special reason?

Comment: @Soner Gönül: Because if necessary Enum1...EnumN I must create N count if statements

Comment: You can consider "switch" statement or refactor your `user` object and use as `if (result != null) user.Enum = code;`

Comment: Depending on how this code is called, you can probably role the conditional in with the setting of `IsEnum1` etc: `user.IsEnum1 = code == SystemCode.Enum1.ToString() && result != null;` or perhaps `|=` if you don't want to set it back to false once you've set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this approach:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Enum1, 
    Enum2, 
    Enum3
}

class User
{
    Dictionary<MyEnum, bool> enumList;

    public void InitEnumList()
    {
        enumList = new Dictionary<MyEnum, bool>();
        foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)))
        {
            //Set the default key-value pairs
            enumList.Add((MyEnum)item, false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch statement is one of the good option for avoiding multiple if statements

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ((  !(code != ((int)SystemCode.Enum1).ToString() || (user.IsEnum1 = result != null).ToString().Length > 0))
    || !(code != ((int)SystemCode.Enum2).ToString() || (user.IsEnum2 = result != null).ToString().Length > 0)
    || !(code != ((int)SystemCode.Enum3).ToString() || (user.IsEnum3 = result != null).ToString().Length > 0))
    {
        return;
    }
```

I know it looks complex but isn't that what you wanted. Let me know if you have any queries.